# Is there a way to expand aliases in a non-interactive sh shell?

Tags: environment-variables, sh, bash, non-interactive

I have a collection of aliases defined in `~/.aliases` which I would like to make available to `sh` even when it is run non-interactively.  My system has been setup in the typical way so that `sh` is a symlink to `bash`.

When bash is run non-interactively as `bash`, this could by using `shopt -s expand_aliases` together with setting `$ENV` or `$BASH_ENV` to (directly or indirectly) source `~/.aliases`.

But when `bash` is invoked non-interactively as `sh`, it seems to ignore `$ENV` and all startup files, so I can't see a way to do it.  Any ideas?  Or is this just not possible?

Comment: Have you tried `~/.bash_aliases` ? Take a look at http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/alias It is working on my box.

Answer (score 2):

One way to force the shell to be interactive when running a script is using `-i` such as:

```
$ bash -i <script>
```

Also, note that if your script has execute permissions, you can replace:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

with:

```
#!/bin/bash -i
```